# apt-get "Broken packages"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

While installing python-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

I am getting the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
python2.7-dev : Depends: python2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
                Depends: libpython2.7 (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu3) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I already have python2.7 and libpython2.7 installed. I don't understand "0ubuntu3" and "0ubuntu3.1" means in the error.

I am on Ubuntu 12.04.
I've tried `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` several times. I've tried googling the problem, but can't find any solution to it. I don't want to `autoremove python`, its gonna remove 300MB of stuff, so I'm guessing more than one thing will stop working.

Since then I have reinstalled Ubuntu 12.04 and have pretty much installed nothing after that, no security updates etc. too. This time python-dev and libboost-dev installed without a hiccup. But am facing the same issue with `freeglut3-dev`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
freeglut3-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                      libgl-dev
                Depends: libglu1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                      libglu-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The feedback I've gotten till now suggests there should be related to the package manager. Has anyone faced this issue? Can someone help please?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your complete sources.list (including anything from sources.list.d/), and also your apt-preference (/etc/apt/preferences*) and the output of `dpkg -l '*' | grep ^h` (if any).

Comment: @phogg: Here are the links, [sources.list](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15363110/sources.list), there is just one file in sources.list.d/ [google-chrome.list](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15363110/google-chrome.list). There are no preferences. There is no output for `dpkg -l '*' | grep ^h`.

Comment: So apparently, this problem fixed itself when I opened the 'Update Manager' -> 'Settings' -> Check all for Update Sources (precise-security, -updates, -proposed, -backports). Close the Settings window. Then hit 'Check' in 'Update Manager' window. This somehow fixed the broken dependencies. And I was able to install everything smoothly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixelbook installing r-base dependency with held broken packages error](https://superuser.com/questions/1422059/pixelbook-installing-r-base-dependency-error)